# how to keep object instances synchronized

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, real-time, distributed-computing

I am working with an object that serves as a database in my application. However, I need to have redundant copies of this database. So, on init, I create multiple instances (say 5) copies of the same object. (I am using JAVA for this, so any hint of pre-existing libraries could be helpful as well.)

The object is a server that listens on a port for request for the information it is holding. This information may be updated by other entities via the same or a different port at any time.

My question is as follows:

- Would a lock strategy
  work in this case? That is, every time an update is made in
  any instance, that instance contacts
  all other instances and passes the
  update.
- During this time, all the requests
  (read or update) from other entities
  are queued.

Would this approach work? I have my doubts because, even if this works, I think the system is creating its own bottleneck. What do you guys say? Is there a better way of doing this distributed synchronization?

Comment: Why do you need to have redundant copies, out of interest?

Comment: Use a _single instance_, and you'll only need to worry about synchronization if you're working in a _multi-threaded environment_ (in which case, you can use the object's _intrinsic lock_ when reading/writing).

Comment: @artbristol @sthupahsmaht Two reasons: First, any server can go down at any time. I am planning to kill some instances during runtime to see how this affects performance. (This is the more important reason.) Second, load balancing - if there are multiple outlets of data, requests to the server will be distributed.

Comment: _all the requests (read or update) from other entities are queued_ ... perhaps [Deques and work stealing](http://codeidol.com/java/java-concurrency/Building-Blocks/Blocking-Queues-and-the-Producer-consumer-Pattern/) would prove useful, although synchronization will still be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a distributed cache.  The big player in that space is currently [Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html) though I believe [JBoss Cache](http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache) is catching up.

As for rolling your own, having seen the complexity in what superficially sounds quite a simple problem, I wouldn't recommend it in a comercial setting, though it'd be a fun home project.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I will look into Coherence. But I was looking to implement my own at a very small scale in my own basement :)

Comment: In that case be sure to check Coherence for inspiration - they've covered off all the issues you're asking about and many more, the big win feature being partitioned caches that you need to obtain scalability.

Comment: Coherence certainly covers the requirement that I have listed above. The main question now is how do I implement it while keeping within the scope. This exercise is understanding how Coherence is implemented. If you have any suggestion on where I should go to develop this understanding, please fire away. Thank you again!

Comment: Start with CAP theory, that's essential in distributed systems.  Then look at Amazon (who do roll-their-own), called Dynamo.  Werner Vogels, their CTO, has presented Dynamo and there's loads of papers stemming from that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a distributed cache? Have you looked at ehcache?

Comment: I guess I am looking for a more lightweight solution. Also, I can't imagine how I would use cache in this setup.

Comment: Ehcache isn't distributed per-se, though you can use it with Terracotta to achieve something that looks like a replicated cache.

Answer (score 0):

There is lot more to distributed syntonization than it's possible to mention in a single answer. You have to worry about two-phase commits, network partitions, etc. etc. I would advise you to look into an existing distributed DB solution combined with an n-tier Java EE architecture that includes load-balancing.

Comment: The scope of my problem is limited and simpler. All the instances that I am creating, are on the same machine. I am using ports just for communication. Also, two-phase commits, if I am to do this real-time, could be costlier - I guess there is no quick fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

> Would this approach work? I have my
>   doubts because, even if this works, I
>   think the system is creating its own
>   bottleneck.

It would be creating its own bottleneck. You'd be better off using an in-memory database like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) or an embedded database like SQLite.

Comment: Even if I use an in-memory db, I am still faced with the synchronization problem...